Google Scholar referring to deleted ResearchGate article
My Google Scholar profile shows citations from deleted ResearchGate articles. RG articles were deleted due to certain issues.
How long does it typically take for such citations to disappear from Google Scholar? It's been over two months, and they are still present

I don't use GS and don't know a lot about it, but I wouldn't expect much of an answer here. It would be nice if you get one, but a lot of questions on this site with this tag have no answers. I think, from reading some of those questions, that GS is pretty opaque with few outside Google itself understanding how it works. The scale of the problem also suggests that it might take a long time to get a resolution. I don't even know whether they have a way to query them or if they respond. But, don't expect any early solution.

Also, see the discussion here: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5376/75368. Note that the discussion itself had no resolution.

Also, what are Research Gate Articles? AFAIK research gate just gathers/links to articles that are published elsewhere. Did this change recently and you can now "publish" there, too?

I'm honestly not sure if GS does any cleanup of references that used to be available, but are not any longer. I suspect there is something related to retractions in place, but if you just uploaded the article to some website and then later deleted it, it may well be that Google will never clean this up.

I can assure you that Google Scholar will eventually clear up these citations if they are no longer in ResearchGate. However, the timing is really on Google's part. It might take a few months (4-6 in my experience) or more.
I accidentally published the pre-release of a paper with the wrong citation, and it took about four months for the citation to stop showing up. I had other cases where people cited me wrongly, and I asked them not to cite me in those instances. It took around six months after they updated their publications to stop showing up. I'd not worry too much about it, though. I assume that Google doesn't do that very often because many researchers would not like to see their h-index going down.

Thank you for sharing your experience. After deleting the article, every time I clicked the URL, it redirected me to the RG homepage. However, just this week, I noticed that the hyperlink on the article is gone, so it is no longer clickable—it's just sitting there.
